# Rails: how to read an external SQLite 3 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a standard Rails 4 app using MongoDB as the database. I want to be able to upload a SQLite 3 file to the application, extract some information, process it and store that in the main db.

The problem is all information I find on the topic is about using SQLite as the main database, not about reading an external file. I guess I won't be able to use ActiveRecord since that would require me to link tables to models and such, but any way that would allow me to browse the data will help. I just need to know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3` gem can be used to open any sqlite3 db files.

Following code opens a file called `data.db`, executes a select query, and writes each row.

```
require "sqlite3"

SQLite3::Database.new( "data.db" ) do |db|
  db.execute( "select * from table" ) do |row|
    p row
  end
end
```

See https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby#synopsis for more details on how to use the gem.